# Pip dependency resolution algorithm (in editable installs)

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, python-poetry, transitive-dependency

There are different and unclear explanations everywhere.
I've checked the contents of wheels and sdists. I've learned about `setup.py`, `setup.cfg`, `pyproject.toml`, `dist-info` (and its `METADATA` file), about the `PKG-INFO` file, and I cannot conciliate all that info.

How does `pip` infer transitive dependencies? where should that info be in built projects (wheels) and source projects (sdists) and in editable installs.

Thanks in advance